# Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit not detecting USB drive at boot

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi4, drive, automount

I reinstalled Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit on my Raspberry Pi 4 and I configured it to automount an external USB drive by editing fstab. The problem is it doesn't detect the drive at boot and it doesn't mount it. If I disconnect the USB cable and reconnect it again then it'll be mounted.

If I try to disconnect the USB cable and reconnect it, the drive is detected and mounted, but I need it to be mounted at boot time.

What should I do to make it be recognized at boot time?
Is it a problem of the 64 bit version?